# Qt and Multipart HTTP

Tags: c++, qt, http, multipart, qt4.7

I have a Qt app that needs to use a multi-part http request.  From looking around on the net I see that multi part requests are being added to Qt4.8 but that is of no use to me now.  I really need the functionality now.

I don't really know how HTTP works so rolling my own solution is beyond me.  If anyone could point me towards a Qt based library or an explanation of how it works then it'd be much appreciated.

Also, I believe the webkit browser included with Qt has support for multi part HTTP requests so if anyone knows how I could use the functionality from webkit to solve my problem it'd be hugely appreciated!

Thanks!

Oscar

Comment: Do you need to serve or fetch multi-part requests (i.e. are you the HTTP server or client)?

Comment: @Judge: The client.  I am trying to do a form submit of a couple of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tuck Design](http://www.tuckdesign.com/sources/Qt) has published a class for handling multipart file uploads that only needs Qt 4.5.